Android USB bulkTransfer to printer fails without error
I have a rather conventional code trying to print to an USB printer and while I have no error messages, the printer, seemingly receiving all bytes, does nothing: neither prints nor signals an error.
I removed logging and error checking from this code to only show the relevant lines but permissions are granted, the interface is the correct one that has the printer class and subclass, all these have been checked thoroughly.
val config = device.getConfiguration(configIndex)
val interfaze = config.getInterface(interfazeIndex)
val endpoint = interfaze.getEndpoint(endpointIndex)
if (endpoint.direction == DIRECTION_OUT && endpoint.type == USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
  UsbManager.openDevice(device)?.also { connection ->
  connection.claimInterface(interfaze, true)
    val bytes = resource.readBytes()
    Thread {
      for (buffer: ByteArray in bytes.chunks(endpoint.maxPacketSize)) {
        val result = connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, buffer, buffer.size, 0)
        if (result < 0) return@Thread
      }
      val result = connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, byteArrayOf(0), 0, 0)
      connection.releaseInterface(interfaze)
      connection.close()
    }.start()
  }
}

I try both bulkTransfer() and UsbRequest(), the symptoms are the same. All transfers return without error, with the expected byte count confirmed, all data to be transmitted is accounted for.
I can only find one suspicious item in logcat — before I establish my connection, I have the following lines:
usbhost                 system_server                        I  usb_device_open /dev/bus/usb/002/002
usbhost                 system_server                        I  usb_device_open open returned 339 writeable 1 errno 0
usbhost                 system_server                        I  usb_device_new /dev/bus/usb/002/002 fd: 339
usbhost                 system_server                        I  usb_device_new read returned 195 errno 0
usbhost                 com.example.usbproof                 I  usb_device_new /dev/bus/usb/002/002 fd: 79
usbhost                 com.example.usbproof                 I  usb_device_new read returned 195 errno 11
UsbProof                com.example.usbproof                 D  connection=android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection@2425168
UsbProof                com.example.usbproof                 D  bytes=116200

This looks like the system tries to open it before me and while it succeeds, my subsequent call gets an EAGAIN error (11). Why can this be so, what can I do about this situation and, additional question, why am I not informed about failure at the app level?
(Just for the record, the printer is functional, the cable is OK, the printer responds to USB discovery queries properly with the very same setup, it's only the printing above that fails.)
